# ReactJs ComponentDidMount

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have some problems with my app, I'm not Javascript expert but it's seams like easy fix.
I need to call like

```
this.props.onNavStyleChange(NAV_STYLE_FIXED);
```

To change my navigation when this page load. But it's giving error like

> Line 13:  Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected ";"

This is the full code

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from "react";
import { Col, Menu, Icon, Row } from "antd";
import { connect } from "react-redux";

import { Redirect, Route, Switch, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import asyncComponent from "util/asyncComponent";
import {
    NAV_STYLE_FIXED,
} from "../../constants/ThemeSetting";

import { onNavStyleChange } from "appRedux/actions/Setting";

componentDidMount() {
    this.props.onNavStyleChange(NAV_STYLE_FIXED);
}


const Dashboard = ({ match, isAuthenticated }) => (


    <div className="gx-main-content-wrapper">

    <Col span={24}>

            <Switch>
                <Redirect exact from={`${match.url}/`} to={`${match.url}/Dashboard`} />

                <Route path={`${match.url}/dashboard`}
                    component={isAuthenticated
                        ? asyncComponent(() => import('./Dashboard'))
                        : () => <Redirect to="/home" />} />


                <Route path={`${match.url}/news`}
                    component={isAuthenticated
                        ? asyncComponent(() => import('./News'))
                        : () => <Redirect to="/home" />} />

                <Route path={`${match.url}/servers`}
                    component={isAuthenticated
                        ? asyncComponent(() => import('./Servers'))
                        : () => <Redirect to="/home" />} />

                <Route path={`${match.url}/billing`}
                    component={isAuthenticated
                        ? asyncComponent(() => import('./Billing'))
                        : () => <Redirect to="/home" />} />


                <Route path={`${match.url}/serverInfo/:id`}
                    component={isAuthenticated
                        ? asyncComponent(() => import('./ServerInfo'))
                        : () => <Redirect to="/home" />} />


                <Route path={`${match.url}/support`}
                    component={isAuthenticated
                        ? asyncComponent(() => import('./Support'))
                        : () => <Redirect to="/home" />} />

            </Switch >
    </Col>
    </div>
);

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        isAuthenticated: state.auth.token !== null
    };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, null)(Dashboard);
```

Comment: `componentDidMount` is a property of `React.Component`/`React.PureComponent`. You'd have to extend one those classes to use it. You can find more information here - https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#adding-lifecycle-methods-to-a-class . Since you're using a FunctionalComponent, you could also use `useEffect` since that's the functional equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

```js
const Dashboard = ({ match, isAuthenticated }) => {

    React.useEffect(() => {
        onNavStyleChange(NAV_STYLE_FIXED);
    }, []);

    return (
        ...
    );
};
```

The [`useEffect` hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) with an empty dependencies array is similar to `componentDidMount`. Inside functional components you'll have to use Hooks instead of class instance methods.

Comment: Yes but in this case says onNavStyleChange is not a function

Comment: I typed that incorrectly. It's an import and not a prop. Please check out my code again.

Answer (score 1):

There's couple of things incorrect in the code but I'll to cover all of it.

1. The error you're seeing is because `componentDidMount` is written as a function but not declared as such.

ie.

```js
function componentDidMount() {
    this.props.onNavStyleChange(NAV_STYLE_FIXED);
}

const componentDidMount = () => {
    this.props.onNavStyleChange(NAV_STYLE_FIXED);
}
```

2. The `componentDidMount` life-cycle is only available in Class-based components.

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  ...
  componentDidMount() { ... }
  ...
}
```

If you want to use functional components, then you'll need to look at hooks. In this case, you'll be looking at [`useEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html).

```
function MyComponent() {
  useEffect(() => {
    ...
  }, [])
}
```